# Why not run service continuous in Android Application?

Tags: android

I'm implementing service in Activity . When start the activity at that i want to start My-service class.But not print any thing on log cat. So how can i know whether is My-service is start or not.

Here is my Activity code for calling service

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(AllPosts_Page.this, MyService.class);
    startService(intent);
```

here is my service code

```
public class MyService extends Service
{
    protected SQLiteDatabase db;
    public Runnable mRunnable = null;
    MyDbHelper myDBHelper;
    String imageName;
    String str_Authentication_Token,str_LoginUserId,str_UserName, result  ;
    ArrayList<String> pics = new ArrayList<String>();

    public MyService() {

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.e("TAG", "ScreenListenerService---OnCreate ");

        myDBHelper = new MyDbHelper(this);
        myDBHelper.onOpen(db);
        //imgUrlLoader=new ImageUrlLoader(getApplicationContext());

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        str_Authentication_Token = sharedPreferences.getString("strAuthentication_Token", "");
        str_LoginUserId = sharedPreferences.getString("strUserId", "");
        str_UserName = sharedPreferences.getString("strUserName", "");

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {

        final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
        mRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                getDoenLoaddata();
                downLoadImages();
                mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 10 * 1000);
            }
        };
        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 10 * 1000);

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    public void getDoenLoaddata() {

        db = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from ActivityObjectList", null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do {
                imageName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("imageaudioPath"));

                pics.add(imageName);}
            while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
    }

    public void downLoadImages()
    {
        for(int i = 0 ; i> pics.size(); i++)
        {
            String picsName = pics.get(i);
            Log.e("picsName "," = " + picsName);
        }
    }
}
```

In my menifest.xml file

```
 <service
            android:name=".MyService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:stopWithTask="false">
        </service>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your manifest.xml , 
make sure your manifest.xml contains "`<service android:name="xx.xx.MyService"></service>`".

Comment: I used you suggestion but why not print this =  Log.e("picsName "," = " + picsName);   anything on log cat .

Comment: I test your code ,it can print "ScreenListenerService---OnCreate ", And I enter the app settings in the phone , this service is started .

Comment: This is laso print  print "ScreenListenerService---OnCreate ", at my site . I m saying , but why not print this  Log.e("picsName "," = " + picsName) in for loop on onStartCommand method in service.

Comment: Evevn this not print  lon log in start command why .   for(int i = 0 ; i> 10; i++)
        {
            Log.e("TAG", "ScreenListenerService---OnCreate ");
        }